# React Native : A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error while I am building APK in my rn project.

OS :Windows

RN Version 0.62

I'm using gradle version 6.3, with the build tool version 3.63

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.3-6040484-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the main work of AAPT2 is to change the resources into binary format. I was getting the same error with image as one of the image size is upto 3Mb so AAPT2 was not able to convert that, so after reducing the size, the applicatikn build gets successful.
In your case there must be some linking issue.